# How to assign unique SVG images to nodes based on labels in Memgraph Lab?

Tags: memgraphdb, memgraph

I need each type of node in a Memgraph Lab graph to have its own specific SVG image. For instance, nodes labeled as 'person' should display 'image1.png', and those labeled as 'place' should use 'image2.png'. I know that Memgraph Lab typically supports a single SVG for all nodes, but I'm looking to implement this more dynamic approach.

Do I need to add image URL as property value to each node? I hope not, since that is exactly that I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each label you can use the Map structure and have label to image mapping in one place:

```
// A map structure to hold the key (label) -> value (url)
Define(IMAGE_BY_LABEL, AsMap(
  "Country", "https://country.svg",
  "Entity", "https://entity.svg",
  "LabelA:LabelB", "https://labela-labelb.svg"
))
Define(DEFAULT_IMAGE_URL, "")

// For all the nodes, get the image from the map structure
@NodeStyle {
  image-url: Get(IMAGE_BY_LABEL, Join(Labels(node), ":"), DEFAULT_IMAGE_URL)
}
```